# this is undefined inside a normal async function (not arrow function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, vue.js, this

This is something that should definitely work and I don't get why it doesn't:

```js
mounted(){ //in object literal
    console.log(this) //prints out the object
    var jq = require('jquery')
    jq(window).scroll(async function() {
        console.log(this) //prints undefined
    })
}
```

I know that if I used `async ()=>{console.log(this)}` then it would definitely be `undefined` but I have no clue why it would be that while using an old-school function? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you used an arrow function, it would definitely *not* be `undefined`, because the `this` would be inherited from the outer scope, where `this` refers to the object

Comment: oh geez something must have messed with my brain, I was sure it was the other way around